# EnvSet + EnvUpdate not setting Env variables permanently from Auto it

Tags: autoit

Friends,

I am setting an environment variable using the EnvSet function followed by the EnvUpdate function. This does not set the environment variable permanently. When I come out of the AutoIt script, the variable retains its original value. How can I permanently set the environment variable from within the AutoIt script?

Sameer

Comment: Same question 8 years ago? https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/44241-envset-envupdate-not-setting-env-variables-permanently/

Comment: Did you try this Run(@ComSpec & " /c " & 'commandName', "", @SW_HIDE) http://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt

Answer (score 1):

Try this for PATH

```
Func _Append2Path($Path2Append)
Const $RegPath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
Local $sSep = ";", $sType = "REG_SZ", $nPath
Local $oPath = RegRead($RegPath, "PATH")
    If @extended = 7 Then
       $sSep = @LF
       $sType = "REG_MULTI_SZ"
    EndIf
    If StringInStr($oPath, $Path2Append) < 1 Then 
       $nPath = $oPath & $sSep & $Path2Append
       RegWrite($RegPath, "PATH", $sType, $nPath)
    EndIf
EndFunc
```

I also found this for temp:

```
RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment", "Temp", "REG_SZ", "C:\Temp")
RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment", "Tmp", "REG_SZ", "C:\Temp")
EnvUpdate()
Sleep(1000)
EnvSet("Temp", "C:\Temp")
EnvSet("Tmp", "C:\Temp")
```